# Separating and counting number of elements in a list with conditions

Tags: shell, for-loop, awk, while-loop

I would like to separate and count the number of elements within my input list.
The input.txt contains 2 columns, $1 is the element ID and $2 is it's ratio (number).

```
ENSG001 12.3107448237
ENSG007 4.3602275
ENSG008 2.9918420285
ENSG009 1.035588
ENSG010 0.999864
ENSG012 0.569833
ENSG013 0.495325
ENSG014 0.253893
ENSG015 0.125389
ENSG017 0.012568
ENSG018 -0.135689
ENSG020 -0.4938497942
ENSG022 -0.6429221854
ENSG024 -1.1759339381
ENSG029 -4.2722999766
ENSG030 -11.8447513281
```

I want to separate the ratios into the following categories:

```
Greater than or equal to 2
Between 1 and 2
Between 0.5 and 1
Between -0.5 and 0.5
Between -1 and -0.5
Between -2 and -1
Less than or equal to 2
```

and then print the count from each category into a single separate output file results.txt:

```
Total   16
 > 2    3
 1 to 2  1
 0.5 to 1    2
-0.5 to 0.5  6
-0.5 to -1   1
-1 to -2     1
 < -2    2
```

I can do this on the command line using the following:

```
awk $2 > 2 {print $1,$2} input.txt | wc -l
awk $2 > 0.5 && $2 < 1 {print $1,$2} input.txt | wc -l
awk $2 > -0.5 && $2 < 0.5 {print $1,$2} input.txt | wc -l
awk $2 > -0.5 && $2 < -1 {print $1,$2} input.txt | wc -l
awk $2 > -1 && $2 < -0.5 {print $1,$2} input.txt | wc -l
awk $2 > -2 && $2 < -1 {print $1,$2} input.txt | wc -l
awk $2 < -2 {print $1,$2} input.txt | wc -l
```

I think there is a quicker way of doing it using a shell script with while or for loop but I don't know how to. Any suggestions would be brilliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just process the file once, the straightforward way would be:

```
awk '$2>=2{a++;next}
$2>0.5 && $2 <1 {b++;next}
$2>-0.5 && $2 <0.5 {c++;next}
...
$2<=-2{x++;next}
END{print "total:",NR;
    print ">2:",a;
    print "1-2:",b;
    ...
    print "<-2:",x
}' file
```

Comment: ah, more concise than mine ^^ +1

Answer (score 2):

You could simply sort the entries numerically, using `sort`, and later count the number of entries in each interval. For example, considering your input:

```
cut -f 2 -d ' ' input.txt | sort -nr | awk '
    BEGIN { split("2 1 0.5 -0.5 -1 -2", inter); i = 1; }
    {
        if (i > 6) { ++c; next; }
        if ($1 >= inter[i]) ++c;
        else if (i == 1) { print c, "greater than", inter[i++]; c = 1; }
        else { print c, "between", inter[i - 1], "and", inter[i++]; c = 1; }
    }
    END { print c, "lower than", inter[i - 1]; }'
```

If your input is already sorted, you may even shorten your command line, using:

```
awk 'BEGIN { split("2 1 0.5 -0.5 -1 -2", inter); i = 1; }
{
    if (i > 6) { ++c; next; }
    if ($2 >= inter[i]) ++c;
    else if (i == 1) { print c, "greater than", inter[i++]; c = 1; }
    else { print c, "between", inter[i - 1], "and", inter[i++]; c = 1; }
}
END { print c, "lower than", inter[i - 1]; }' input.txt
```

And the resulting output -- which you may format as you will:

```
3 greater than 2
1 between 2 and 1
2 between 1 and 0.5
6 between 0.5 and -0.5
1 between -0.5 and -1
1 between -1 and -2
2 lower than -2
```

Comment: This one should be chosen... It really answer's the OP's wish to have a while/for loop, ie a way to separate the program/method from the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to implement this with a single awk command by maintaining a running count for each category you are interested in.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 INPUT"
    exit 1
fi

awk ' {
  if      ($2 >  2)   count[0]++
  else if ($2 >  1)   count[1]++
  else if ($2 >  0.5) count[2]++
  else if ($2 > -0.5) count[3]++
  else if ($2 > -1)   count[4]++
  else if ($2 > -2)   count[5]++
  else count[6]++
} END {
  print "      >  2\t",   count[0]
  print " 1   to  2\t",   count[1]
  print " 0.5 to  1\t",   count[2]
  print "-0.5 to  0.5\t", count[3]
  print "-1   to -0.5\t", count[4]
  print "-2   to -1\t",   count[5]
  print "      < -2\t",   count[6]
}' $1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

with `script.awk`:

```
{
    if ($2>=2) counter1++
    else if ($2>=1) counter2++
    else if ($2>=0.5) counter3++
    else if ($2>=-0.5) counter4++
    else if ($2>=-1) counter5++
    else if ($2>=-2) counter6++
    else counter7++
}
END{
    print "Greater than 2: "counter1
    print "Between 1 and 2: "counter2
    print "Between 0.5 and 1: "counter3
    print "Between -0.5 and 0.5: "counter4
    print "Between -1 and -0.5: "counter5
    print "Between -2 and -1: "counter6
    print "Less than 2: "counter7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

script toto:

```
awk '
      $2>2                  { count[1]++; label[1]="Greater than or equal to 2"; }
     ($2>1    && $2<=2)     { count[2]++; label[2]="Between 1 and 2"; }
     ($2>0.5  && $2<=1)     { count[3]++; label[3]="Between 0.5 and 1"; }
     ($2>-0.5 && $2<=0.5)   { count[4]++; label[4]="Between -0.5 and 0.5"; }
     ($2>-1   && $2<=-0.5)  { count[5]++; label[5]="Between -1 and -0.5"; }
     ($2>-2   && $2<=-1)    { count[6]++; label[6]="Between -2 and -1"; }
                 $2<=-2     { count[7]++; label[7]="Less than or equal to 2"; }

    END { for (i=1;i<=7;i++)
           {   printf "%-30s %s\n" ,label[i], count[i];
           }
        }
    '  /tmp/input.txt
```

and the result:

```
. /tmp/toto

Greater than or equal to 2     3
Between 1 and 2                1
Between 0.5 and 1              2
Between -0.5 and 0.5           6
Between -1 and -0.5            1
Between -2 and -1              1
Less than or equal to 2        2
```

Comment: fixed. I go for clarity over terseness ^^

Comment: Haha! Thanks for the comments! It's the OP that chooses what is best for their own purposes (: Your alternative is very neat too! ^^